# Google AdMob RPM calculation

Tags: admob

First off, if this question does not belong on SO, please direct me to a SE site where it should be.

I currently have in my app a bunch of AdMob banners that display -- a new one displays for each page transition.  This means that more ads are loaded than if I just had only one obviously.  Does this mean that my RPM (revenue earned per thousand impressions, or loaded ads) will go down because the click-through rate (percentage of people that actually clicked the ad) is lower?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how often users are transitioning between you pages. If they transition more often that the refresh rate of your ad banners then you will see a lower RPM because you will be making more ad requests that otherwise for the same amount of user clicks.

IMHO you are better off having a single AdView and reorganise your pages into Fragments that are shown alongside your single AdView.

Unless you have distinct types of content of each page that require that specifically filtered ads be shown it is unlikely to be a good reason for you to have multiple AdViews.